# Why is my method printing multiple times?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have three different programs that all read in from each other. One method creates a toString method for individual objects, the second reads in a file with a list of individual objects, and the third creates an additional toString method that calls the first one and creates a toString for the second method to use. The information is printing multiple times, and I can't figure out why. iList is an array list that contains various objects. The output I am getting is correct, but it is just printing four times instead of one.

toString method in first program:

```
public String toString() {

  NumberFormat dollarFmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  DecimalFormat percentFmt = new DecimalFormat("#.0%");

  String output = "\nDescription: " + description.trim(); 
  output += "\nCost: " + dollarFmt.format(cost); 
  output += "   Percent Depreciation: " 
     + percentFmt.format(percentDepreciated);    
  output += "\nCurrent Value: " 
     + dollarFmt.format(cost - (cost * percentDepreciated));

  if (isEligibleToScrape()) {
     output += "\n*** Eligible to scrape ***";
  }   

  if (percentDepreciatedOutOfRange()) {
     output += "\n*** Percent Depreciated appears to be out of range ***";
  }
}
```

toString method in third program:

```
public String toString() { 

  String output = ("\n" + inventoryName + "\n");

  int index = 1;
  while (index < iList.size()) {

     output += (iList.toString());  

     index++;
  }

  return output;
}
```

Calling toString from the third program in the second program:

```
Inventory myInventoryList 
     = new Inventory(inventoryName, inventoryList);

  System.out.println(myInventoryList.toString());
```

Comment: where is your second program?

Comment: because you are calling `toString()` recursively inside second program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this : `output += (iList.get(index).toString());`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `iList.toString()` to the output multiple times :

```
  while (index < iList.size()) {

     output += (iList.toString());  

     index++;
  }
```

That's why it's printing multiple times.

I don't know what's the type of `iList`, but it looks like it's some kind of list, so you probably want to add a String representation of an element of the list to the output in each iteration of the while loop (instead of the entire list every time).

Since `iList` is an ArrayList, you need to change the loop to :

```
  int index = 0;
  while (index < iList.size()) {
     output += iList.get(index).toString();   
     index++;
  }
```

Or :

```
  for (int i=0; i<iList.size();i++)
     output += iList.get(i).toString();
```

Of course it would be better to append the output to a StringBuilder instead of creating a new String in each iteration.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. I used the while loop because I need to print each of the objects contained in iList (InventoryItems). How could I do that?

Comment: @kb94 What's the type of iList? You need to call a method that returns the i'th item of that list, and run toString on that item.

Comment: iList is an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
while (index < iList.size()) {
  output += (iList.toString());  
  index++;
}
```

to something like (assuming `iList` is a `List`)

```
while (index < iList.size()) {
  output += iList.get(index); // <-- toString() is implicit here  
  index++;
}
```

Which will [`get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) the individual item to be printed (instead of printing the entire `List` each time) and (implicitly) invoke `toString()` (which you have already overridden).

Comment: you are missing `iList.get(index).toString()`

Comment: @Rustam No I'm not, it's still there implicitly because `output` is a `String`.

Comment: i think it is not `overriden` one so it will be as normal method. m i ryt?

Comment: @Rustam What is not `overriden`? It'll still implicitly call `toString()` on the Object returned by the `List.get(int)`